# Kotlin - The caracter literal does not conform expect type Int

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

I'm struggling with types with my program, I've been asked to do it in JS first and it worked fine but now I can't achieve the result.
Do you think I should make another 'algorithm' ? In advance, thank you for your time.

```
fun main(){
    // the idea is to put numbers in a box
    // that cant be larger than 10
    val data = "12493419133"
    var result = data[0]
    var currentBox = Character.getNumericValue(data[0])
    var i = 1

    while(i < data.length){

        val currentArticle =  Character.getNumericValue(data[i])
         currentBox += currentArticle

        println(currentBox)

        if(currentBox <= 10){
            result += Character.getNumericValue(currentArticle)
        }else{
            result += '/'
            //var resultChar = result.toChar()
            // result += '/'
            currentBox = Character.getNumericValue(currentArticle)
            result += currentArticle
        }
        i++
    }
    print(result) //should print 124/9/341/91/33
}
```

Comment: Please, describe what is your output and what you want to achieve. If there are any errors, paste them too.

Comment: Hello, the output should be 124/9/341/91/33 as I'm trying to separate the string data in "boxes" that can't contain more than 10. Basically if it does it create another one "/" and continues to loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is actually of a `Char` type, and the overload operator function `+` only accepts Int to increment ASCII value to get new Char.

```kotlin
public operator fun plus(other: Int): Char
```

In idomatic Kotlin way, you can solve your problem:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val data = "12493419133"

    var counter = 0
    val result = data.asSequence()
        .map(Character::getNumericValue)
        .map { c ->
            counter += c
            if (counter <= 10) c.toString() else "/$c".also{ counter = c }
        }
        .joinToString("")  // terminal operation, will trigger the map functions

    println(result)
}
```

**Edit:** If the `data` is too large, you may want to use StringBuilder because it doesn't create string every single time the character is iterated, and instead of using a counter of yourself you can use `list.fold()`

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val data = "12493419133"

    val sb = StringBuilder()
    data.fold(0) { acc, c ->
        val num = Character.getNumericValue(c)
        val count = num + acc
        val ret = if (count > 10) num.also { sb.append('/') } else count
        ret.also { sb.append(c) }  // `ret` returned to ^fold, next time will be passed as acc
    }

    println(sb.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a result in `List<Char>` type:

```
val data = "12493419133"
val result = mutableListOf<Char>()
var sum = 0
data.asSequence().forEach {
    val v = Character.getNumericValue(it)
    sum += v
    if (sum > 10) {
        result.add('/')
        sum = v
    }
    result.add(it)
}
println(result.joinToString(""))
```